# MySQL from_unixtime() and Python time.ctime() not agreeing

Tags: python, mysql, time, unix-timestamp

I have some data that uses `unixtime`. I'm using Python and MySQL.

I have noticed that the MySQL GUI Tools function `from_unixtime()` doesn't equal Python's output of  `time.ctime()` or even the MySQL cmd line interface...

MySQL Command Line:

```
#This returns the correct time

mysql> select from_unixtime(1295147016.45300);
+---------------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1295147016.45300) |
+---------------------------------+
| 2011-01-15 21:03:36             |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

MySQL GUI Tools:

```
# Incorrect Time!

select from_unixtime(1295147016.45300);

2011-01-16 03:03:36
```

Python:

```
#This returns the correct time

>>> import time
>>> time.ctime(1295147016.45300)
'Sat Jan 15 21:03:36 2011'
```

Can someone please shed some light on the discrepancies? What's the point of having a GUI if it doesn't show the correct data.

Thanks,
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time zone is different in both the cases. Just fix the time-zone in MySQL GUI tools and you're good to go.